# Is it possible to change the way Kubernetes assigns IPs to pods

Tags: selenium, kubernetes, selenium-grid

**The scenario**: Selenium is a browser automation tool that can be run in a K8s cluster, it consists of Selenium-hub (master) and selenium-nodes (workers) where the hub receives test requests and creates nodes (pods) ondemand (dynamically) to run the test-case, after execution of a test-case the runner node (pod) gets thrown away. also, Selenium supports live-preview of the test being run by the runner and a client (outside of K8s) can basically watch this live preview, there is a little change that when a client is watching the live preview of the test and it ends, another pod gets created with the same IP that the client is actually is still watching, this is a problem since the client may continue watching the run of another test because the client's software is not aware of the length of run and may still fetch the traffic with same user/pass/IP combination.

**The question**: is it possible to change the way Kubernetes assigns IP addresses?
let's say the first pod to be created gets IP 1.1.1.1 and the second one gets 1.1.1.2 and third 1.1.1.3, and before the fourth request the first pod dies and its IP is free then the fourth pod would be created with IP 1.1.1.1,

What I am trying to do is to tell to the Kubernetes to use previously assigned IP after some time or change the sequence of IP assignment or something similar.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2):

Technically: yes you can either configure or edit-the-code of your CNI plugin (or write one from scratch).

In practice: I know of none that work quite that way. I know Calico does allow having multiple IP pools so you could have a small one just for Selenium pods but I think it still attempts to minimize reuse. But check the docs for your CNI plugin and see what it offers.